# select span text with jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I have this html code, I want get span text when click in reply, but I have multiple of this code in my page and this select only first item, this is my code

```
<div class="display-comment" style="margin-right: 10px">
    <div class="userProfileImageForComment">
        <img src="{{asset('profile-media/'.$comment->user->profileimg)}}" alt="">
    </div>
    <span id="userName">{{ $comment->user->username }}</span>
    <p>{{ $comment->comment }}</p>
    <div class="comentActionAndDate">
        <span>
            {{ jdate($comment->created_at)->ago() }}
        </span>
        <a id="reply">
            reply
        </a>
    </div>
```

and script is

```
<script>
    $('#reply').click(function(){
        var username = "@" + $('#userName').text() + " ";
        $('#comment').val('');
        $('#comment').val(username);

        $('#comment').after( "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"comment_id\" value=\"{{ $comment->id }}\" />" )

    });
</script>
```

Comment: you have to declare a different id for the span and get the value of them according to their id

Comment: Id must be unique, use `class` instead of `id` .

Answer (score 0):

you can do get your span text with this comnmand:

```
$('#userName')[0].innerText
```

anything else?

Answer (score 0):

```
var spanText = $(".comentActionAndDate span").html();
```

I assume this is for a comments thread though, in which case you should use relative finding to locate the text.

```
$('#reply').click(function(){
    var spanText = $(this).find(".comentActionAndDate").children("span").html();
    // Other stuff you might want to do
});
```

You also should **not** be using an ID for that reply button if it is being generated more than once. You should also be using a `<button>` not an `<a>` tag as the `a` tag is used for links.

The most correct approach would be to use a function `onclick` of the reply button:

```
<button onclick="getSpan(this);">reply</button>
```

JS:

```
function getSpan(ele) {
    var spanText = $(ele).find(".comentActionAndDate").children("span").html();
    // Other stuff you might want to do
}
```